# Learning to work with databases - from web to desktop application

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010

I have experience with MySQL as a web developer. I also have some experience with desktop applications, but I have never needed a database in one. Now I want to create a simple desktop application for me, which I would like to make in Visual Studio C#. I know I can work with database in C#, but I have some noob questions, which are not answered by tutorials I've browsed through so far.

There are obviously more solutions, what would you recommend for simple application aimed to work with vocabulary for new languages learning?

What does a database mean for application installation? Can I keep it simple, so that I could than run the application on other computer without installing something more for the database to work?

I would appreciate some tutorials, or advice on start.

Comment: No enough information, and not entirely clear what you are asking for. What is the usage scenario for this database? One user/application? Multiple users?

Comment: [StackOverflow is not a search engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128549/172661). Questions about where to find things like tutorials or product recommendations belong at Google (or your favorite search engine). This site is for **specific** programming questions. Keeping questions on-topic helps keep clutter down and makes this a useful programming resource. Thanks.

Comment: That is what I meant with "are not answered by tutorials I've browsed through so far." I am sorry if these questions are really basic, but I did spent some time browsing web and also SO and then I tried to ask. I understand the concept.

Comment: Oded: I was thinking only one user, possible more in the future. I figure out I need a db, because I would like to sort the words in vocabulary, find translation or pick one random added day/week/month earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to find a question, but I think I found one - you're asking how to install a database with an application.

If every user of your application sees her own copy of the data, with no sharing, then MySQL is probably an overkill. You should take a look at [SQLite](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/) instead. There's no installation at all.

Answer (score 4):

If it's a simple application you could go with [Microsoft SQL CE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact) database - CE means Compact Edition. You can then install the app in whatever computer and just place the accompanying database file in a directory of your choice and should be good to go. There's no database server involved and as a result it's pretty light when deploying the app.